# Failed to check if SpannedString contains certain character in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, spanned

I have html content string that is converted to Spanned using `Html.fromHtml(this, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)`. I want to check if it contains bullet point character "•" using both `htmlValue.contains("•")` and `htmlValue.contains(Regex("•"))`. None of them works.

But when i try to replace that character using `htmlValue.replace(Regex("•"), ""),` it works. Why did that happens and how do i determine if SpannedString contains certains character?